# Send authorization request from React to Spring REST

Tags: reactjs, spring, rest

I am trying to authenticate a react application with a rest api built with spring boot and configured with spring security.

Currently I am getting a 302 error even with correct user credentials.

Is "/login" the correct default URL for the post request authentication information?
In addition, do I simply need to add a csrf token to the header and the username/password to the post request body?

The security configuration looks like the following:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
```

My post looks like this:

```js
...
const data = { 
            userName: this.state.userName,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")},
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }).then(response => {
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove httpBasic is contradictory with formLogin, then I would recommend use simple html form post to do login because of spring security's behavior, it has a config to redirect after login: .loginPage("/login").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/loginCheck").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")

Answer (score 0):

You have to give login.html page in the configure method like this.

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login.html").permitAll();
```

Refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Hope this will solve your problem :)